# Solving $ \frac{dv}{dt} =-\mu g-kv^2 $

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

> > Question: In the sport of curling a stone of mass $m$ is bowled along the surface of a frozen lake with an initial velocity $u$ and is gradually slowed down by frictional forces and air resistance. Its velocity $v$ at a distance $x$ from where it is bowled is given by the differential equation $$ v\frac{dv}{dx} = -\mu g-kv^2 $$ where $\mu$ is a constant, $g$ is the constant of acceleration due to gravity and $k$ is a constant/
> >
> > $(i)$ By solving the differential equation show that the stone eventually comes to a rest at a distance $X$ from where it is bowled where $$ X = \frac{1}{2k}
> > ln(1+\frac{k u^2}{\mu g})$$
> >
> > $(ii)$ If $t$ is the time which has elapsed from when the stone is bowled to when its velocity is $v$ then since $v\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dt} \cdot \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{dv}{dt}$, the differential becomes  $$\frac{dv}{dt} =-\mu g-kv^2 $$
> >
> > Show that $$tan(\sqrt{k \mu g} t) =\frac{ \sqrt{k \mu g}(u-v)}{\mu g + uvk} $$

---

What I have done

for $(i)$ $$ v\frac{dv}{dx} = -\mu g-kv^2 $$

$$ ⇔ \int \frac{v}{-\mu g-kv^2} dv = \int dx$$

$$⇔ - \int\frac{v}{\mu g+kv^2} dv = \int dx $$

$$⇔ -\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g+kv^2|= x+c $$

At $x=0$ , $v=u$ $ \therefore c =-\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g+ku^2|$

$$⇔ -\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g+kv^2|= x-\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g+ku^2| $$

At $v=0$, $x=X$

$$⇔ -\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g|= X-\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g+ku^2| $$

$$⇔ -\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g|= X-\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g(1+\frac{ku^2}{\mu g})|$$

$$⇔ -\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g|= X-\frac{1}{2k} \ln|\mu g| -\frac{1}{2k}\ln|1+\frac{ku^2}{\mu g}|$$

$$ \therefore X = \frac{1}{2k}
\ln(1+\frac{k u^2}{\mu g})  $$

---

Now $(ii)$ is the part I am stuck on , I have tried this

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} =-\mu g-kv^2 $$

$$  -\int \frac{dv}{\mu g+kv^2} = \int dx  $$

I tried factoring out the constants out at this point and using a trig sub but that did not work as the constants keep getting in the way

Answer (score 1):

The integral can be written as:
$$\frac{1}{k} \int \frac{dv}{a^2+v^2}=-\int dx$$ Where $a=\sqrt\frac{\mu g}{k}$

Now, this is the standard $\arctan$ integral, which evaluates to: $$\frac{1}{ka} \tan^{-1} {v\over a}=-x+C$$
Now you can put $a$ back.

**Edit:** If you're interested in a trig sub, write your integral as:
$$\frac{1}{k}\int \frac{dv}{\frac{\mu g}{k}+v^2}$$
And then substitute $$v=\sqrt{\frac{\mu g}{k}} \tan \theta$$
It should work out.